# Changing ASIO device when unconnected

Tags: sound, daw

There's a lot of stuff using ASIO drivers on the markets. My question is:
If I use several devices, used by ASIO, can I somehow tweak the behaviour of ASIO in such a case, that in case of the disconnection of my primary audio device (e.g. external mixer via USB), ASIO switches to a Fallback-Solution?

Comment: try with Asio4all but i can't garantee it.